# Why am I getting the 'field is required' validation error even though the field is passed with the form?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am writing a .NET Core 3.0 MVC Web app. I have a `JobApplication` model that looks like this:

```
    public class JobApplication
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id{ get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyy-MM-dd}")]
        [Display(Name = "Edited on:")]
        public DateTime? EditedOn { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyy-MM-dd}")]
        [Display(Name = "Deleted on:")]
        public DateTime? DeletedOn { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public User Applicant { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public JobOffer JobOffer { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public ApplicationStatus ApplicationStatus { get; set; }

        public string CvHandle { get; set; }
        public string AdditionalInformation { get; set; }
    }
```

As you can see, the model holds references to the Job Offer it was created for and the applicant that created the application.

I also have a Controller `JobApplicationController` that has 2 `Create` methods:

```
        public async Task<ActionResult> Create(int? id)
        {
            var offer = await _context.JobOffers.Include(x => x.CreatedFor).FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id.Value);
            var user = await _context.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Name == "Filip");

            var model = new JobApplication()
            {
                JobOffer = offer,
                Applicant = user
            };
            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Create([FromForm]JobApplication model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(model);
            }

            JobApplication ja = new JobApplication
            {
             ...
            };

            await _context.JobApplications.AddAsync(ja);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

As you can see, one of them returns the `Create` view, the other gets the model from the view and adds it to the database. I also emphasize that in the first method, the 'JobOffer' and 'Applicant' fields are taken from the database and passed to the form with a model. Here's how the view is set up:

```
@model HRpest.BL.Model.JobApplication

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            @Html.Hidden("Offer", Model.JobOffer)
            @Html.Hidden("Applicant", Model.Applicant)
            <div asp-validation-summary="None" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="CvHandle" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="CvHandle" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="CvHandle" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="AdditionalInformation" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="AdditionalInformation" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="AdditionalInformation" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

It all seems fine. However, when I try to add an application and submit the form, I get an error:

```
{"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1","title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"|a72c03fc-4f6501d7781e4a9a.","errors":{"JobOffer":["The JobOffer field is required."],"Applicant":["The Applicant field is required."]}}
```

I don't understand it. I have both fields in my model. How to make this go away?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Instead of Hidden can you try HiddenFor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use HiddenFor() Instead of Hidden().

Read [here](https://www.completecsharptutorial.com/asp-net-mvc5/html-hiddenfor-example-aspnet-mvc5.php) to understand the difference between the two.

Answer (score 1):

I think is because required too. Because navigation property is complex object and should not be required

```cs
        public virtual User Applicant { get; set; }

        public virtual JobOffer JobOffer { get; set; }

        public virtual ApplicationStatus ApplicationStatus { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

In the view, you are saying, `@Html.Hidden("Offer", Model.JobOffer)`. It should instead be `@Html.Hidden("JobOffer", Model.JobOffer)` because that's the property name. You wouldn't make that mistake if you were using HiddenFor.

On a more abstract level, you are binding directly to the database entity. It's never a good idea. You should use a model to get the posted values and then copy those values to the entity. You can use AutoMapper to do that automatically for you.

Comment: Thank you, that's a great suggestion.